# Posting a question about a free Windows utility

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about an issue (probably a bug) with a Windows search utility called **Agent Ransack**. Would it be appropriate to ask it somewhere on StackExchange and if yes, in which area.

Comment: Probably SuperUser

Comment: Bug reports should go to that product's support bug tracker.

Comment: Agreed with Mat.  Post a bug with the Agent Ransack folks.

Comment: It really depends, if it's a question about using its regex engine for example - then probably yes.

Comment: Sorry, I should have given more detail about the issue. (Obviously, I'm not asking you to help with this; just to clarify my question). The tool doesn't clear or update its search history as it's supposed to. I re-installed it a few times, but that didn't help. If I submit a bug report, that probably won't help short-term. I'm sure they have a support forum, but I prefer using StackExchange because it's so much better.

Comment: No, this is not suitable for Stack Overflow in any shape or form, as it isn't really about programming. As others have commented - you should post a bug with Agent Ransack.